How to save/download a pdf file from browser's pdf preview in Playwright
I am using this sample PDF.
https://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/http-response-codes-1.pdf
My goal is to download this as a pdf file.
Here is my code so far
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  // await page.emulateMedia({ media: 'print' }); // Doesn't work also.
  await page.emulateMedia({ media: 'screen' });

  await page.goto('https://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/http-response-codes-1.pdf');

  console.log('Page Visited');

  await page.waitForTimeout(3000); // To wait for the pdf to be full loaded.

  console.log('Timeout Done');

  await page.pdf({ path: `document.pdf` });

  console.log('Document Saved');

  await browser.close();
})();

It does save the document but the content is broken.
Example this is what the document looks like on a browser controlled by playwright.

But this is what was saved locally

Not sure what is going on here.
I tried the screenshot approach and it does behave the same way.
I tried the triggering of ctrl+s but learned that this is not possible due to security reasons. I am a bit lost.
Any help is appreciated.
But my overall goal is to download a pdf file from the pdf preview of the browser.

Why use Puppeteer to make a PDF of a PDF preview screen rather than using fetch, which is the standard way to download a file in Node? Puppeteer's PDF function is used to make a PDF from a webpage. You mention two separate goals: one, downloading a PDF, and two, downloading a PDF from the PDF preview screen. The second seems like a rather unusual goal to want to have--are you trying to capture the preview frame along with the PDF...?

@ggorlen This is a part of a bigger codebase. Basically I am automating a workflow that by the end of it, will produce a pdf file. I wanted to download the output pdf file. The output pdf file cannot be downloaded publicly, only within the context of the current page which is authenticated.

@Jplus2 I'm confused because the link you provided downloads publicly for me. If the file you've provided is not the actual PDF, then it seems like the example doesn't reproduce the actual problem and more accuracy to the actual use case is necessary. Because there's a very simple two-liner which is the correct way to download the link you've provided. I tested it and it works.

Chromium has a built-in PDF viewer extension that shows you a webpage with the PDF embedded in it after you navigate to a PDF file so you can preview it. So you're downloading a webpage containing the PDF instead of the PDF itself.
I tried using $('#download').get(0).click() using jQuery in the Chrome console, but looks like the console can't detect the code that was injected by the extension. It might work with Playright.
But you should just use fetch() to download the file itself anyways. If you're doing automated end-to-end testing, there's no reason to test the functionality of the extension anyways.
